# How does pandas to_dict deal with key np.nan and None?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = {np.nan: -1, None: 1}
```

take a look at `a`:

```py
{nan: -1, None: 1}
```

if we convert it from Series back to dict:

```py
pd.Series(a).to_dict()
```

we see:

```py
{nan: -1, nan: 1}
```

how could Pandas create the dict with two *same* keys? Well, I guess they are not really the same since `np.nan == np.nan` evaluates to False. But I can't create it manually with:

```py
b = {np.nan: -1, np.nan: 1}
```

if we take a look at `b` it gives:

```py
{nan: 1}
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around this, maybe I missed something obvious?

For the full code snippet, see image

[image]

this also shows that I can keep adding the key `np.nan` to the dict generated from pandas series to_dcit, but not my manually created ones

Comment: The keys used by `to_dict` are `float("nan")`, and apparently you can create a dict with multiples `float("nan")` keys (try `d = {float("nan"): 1, float("nan"):2}`), but will not be able to access them. So looking into `float("nan")` internals seems the way.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with `float("nan")` internals, take a look:

```
In [24]: s = pd.Series({np.nan: -1, None: 1})
    ...: d = s.to_dict()

In [25]: d
Out[25]: {nan: -1, nan: 1}

In [26]: [type(k) for k in d.keys()]
Out[26]: [<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]

In [27]: d[float("nan")] = 3

In [28]: d
Out[28]: {nan: -1, nan: 1, nan: 3}

In [29]: d[np.nan] = 100

In [30]: d
Out[30]: {nan: -1, nan: 1, nan: 3, nan: 100}

In [31]: d[np.nan] = 1000

In [32]: d
Out[32]: {nan: -1, nan: 1, nan: 3, nan: 1000}
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import pandas as pd

r={'A':{1:2,2:3,3:4},'B':{1:np.nan,2:44,3:np.nan}}
data = pd.(r)
```

```
   A   B
1  2 nan
2  3  44
3  4 nan
```